# Set variable to HTML elements with certain class?

Tags: javascript

I'm sure there is a way to set a JavaScript variable to any HTML element with a certain class attached to it? I'm just not sure how to write it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Get a list of element references using `document.getElementsByClassName`, then loop through it. PIE.

Comment: @Rob W - is getElementsByClassName supported by ie?

Comment: no, getElementsByClassName is only in IE9 - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use a framework, such as jquery, that makes an easy use of (css) selectors, e.g, to select all elements with class `my-class` do

```
$('.my-class')
```

and then apply any code to the list of those elements

edit: don't forget to use the `$(document).ready` wrapper

Comment: If Op can figure out how to include the jquery script this is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply go var x = document.getElementById('somediv'); for example.  Now whatever style class pertains to somediv will of course still obtain unless you change it programatically in your javascript.

Hope that helps -- might be able to be more helpful if you give a broader context of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without `document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')` nor `$(.'myclass')` would be difficult and require some advanced tactics. You would have to `recursively generate` a list of all DOM objects from the document. While generating the list, every element touched would have to be tested for `.className = 'myclass'`. This is essentially what jquery does behind the scenes, although I believe on page load it caches the whole DOM for easier querying.